# out of bound exception because for loop doesn't move to next loop/index

Tags: c++, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I am doing leetcode problem 289. Game of Life
while running my code which I pasted below I get the following error

Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x608000000020 overflowed to 0x608000000008 (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

I tried to use print statements to get an idea about the problem which seems to be the for loop works for the index[0][0] and doesn;t move to next index. I have pasted the print statement below as well. Will be very thankful if someone could help me out

0 for loop i 0 for loop j
0input row
0row
1col
1count
0input row
1row
0col
1count
0input row
-1row
0col

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    int countLives(vector<vector<int>>& board, int & i, int &j)
    {
        int count=0;
        vector<vector<int>> directions={{0,1},{1,0},{-1,0},{0,-1},{-1,-1},{1,1},                {-1,1},{1,-1}};
        for(int k=0;k<directions.size();k++)
        {
                int r=(i+directions[k][0]);
            cout<<i<<"input row"<<endl;
            cout<<r<<"row"<<endl;
                int c=j+directions[k][1];
            cout<<c<<"col"<<endl;
                if(r>=0 && r<board.size() && c>=0 && c<board[0].size() && board[r][c]==1|| board[r][c]==2) 
                    count++;
            cout<<count<<"count"<<endl;
            

        }
            
        return count;
    };
    
    void gameOfLife(vector<vector<int>>& board) {
        if(board.size()==0)
            return;
        for(int i=0;i<board.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<board[0].size();j++)
            {
                cout<<i<<" for loop i "<<j<<" for loop j"<<endl; 
                
                int count=countLives(board,i,j);
                if(board[i][j]==1 && count<2 || count>3)
                   board[i][j]=2;
                if(board[i][j]==0 && count==3)
                    board[i][j]=3;
            }
        }
        cout<<"done counting"<<endl;
          for(int i=0;i<board.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<board[0].size();j++)
            {
                if(board[i][j]==3)
                    board[i][j]=1;
                if(board[i][j]==2)
                    board[i][j]=0;
            }}
        
        
    }
};
```

Comment: I get 19 errors when I compile the code as presented. I recommend adding the headers.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(r>=0 && r<board.size() && c>=0 && c<board[0].size() && board[r][c]==1|| board[r][c]==2)
```

The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence, and so this is parsed as

```
if( (r>=0 && ... && board[r][c]==1) || board[r][c]==2)
```

So if, for instance, `r` is negative, the left-hand operand of `||` will be false and the program will then evaluate the right-hand operand `board[r][c]==2`, which is of course invalid because `r` is negative.

You probably meant

```
if(r>=0 && r<board.size() && c>=0 && c<board[0].size() && (board[r][c]==1 || board[r][c]==2))
```

and you might also want to break it across several lines so that it's more readable.  That might have made the bug easier to spot.

As a general rule, whenever mixing `&&` and `||` in an expression, always use explicit parentheses rather than relying on operator precedence.  (Whoever reads your code may find the precedence hard to remember too.)

There is a similar bug at

```
if(board[i][j]==1 && count<2 || count>3)
```

Comment: Hi, truly very thankful to you for your help. When I put parenthesis around the or statements I actually did not have the issue anymore, however, I don't understand, if I am making precedence related mistakes in a function I am calling in a for loop, how does the for loop prevent the for loop from moving to the next loop.

Comment: what I meant to say is I still don't understand how did this mistake gave rise to the out of bound error

Comment: @Nnl As I said, when  `r` is `-1`, due to this bug you access `board[-1][0]` which is certainly out of bounds.  (It looks like the index is internally treated as unsigned, so using `-1` wraps around and behaves like a very large positive index, which is also out of bounds.)  I suspect the sanitizer aborts the program when this happens which is why your for loop doesn't "move on".  That's a good thing, it prevents the program from going on and failing in more subtle or harmful ways (corrupting data, security holes, etc).

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for taking your time to help me out with your expertise, I learned something valuable from it and wholeheartedly appreciate it a lot. I actually did not think about the -1 situation

Comment: @Nnl: You're welcome!  I'm glad it was helpful.

Comment: hi  I sincerely apologize for my late response,when I saw the notification I was doing something then I forgot to come back, I hope you don't  feel disrespected and unappreciated for the help you have given me